# Magneto 2.3.1 'Quantity source' becomes null when create product with the same name

Tags: magento2, product, inventory, multi-source-inventory

I have **Magento 2.3.1** setup and **multiple products**,

**When I am trying to create a new product with the same name**, it is allowed me to create the product with the same name but the '**Inventory Sources**' **become blank**.

after saving the same name product it removes the '**Inventory Sources**' which are assigned to product on the product add form.

==> **One more thing I found " If I use different SKU on product save then it will save the Inventory Sources as well ".**

==> **But if we use the same SKU for the product it will save the product and change the SKU by itself with adding '-1' after SKU but this way it won't save the Inventory Sources.**

Is anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue you described may be caused by changing the SKU. Inventory in Magento 2.3.1 is using product SKU as a natural identifier, therefore changing the product's SKU may cause problems with quantities.

There is an interesting conversation on the subject in one of the tickets on MSI repository: https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/2001